# xorg source code copy paste

Tags: linux, xorg

Anybody knows where in xorg source code is located copy/paste routine which is bind to left(copy) and middle(paste) mouse buttons?

**More datails**:
When you select any text in X session by using left mouse button (normal text selection), it is copied to some "clipboard". Next, when you click middle mouse button in any input control/window text is pasted.

**Why I need it**:
I need it because I want to change this functionality a little. It is very useful comparing to MsWindows Ctrl-c Ctrl-v. Much faster. But it would be even more if under some button we can reach for previous clipboard content. In this case we can replace one text by other like this:

1. selecting text A
2. selecting destination text B (in this moment under middle button text A was overwritten by B)
3. paste text A using SOME button (not middle button)

Answer (score 2):

It's not in the Xorg source code, but in the sources for each X toolkit or application.  The X server simply sends the application the mouse button events, which get processed through its event handling to whatever functions they've bound to those buttons.  The copy & paste mechanism you describe is a common convention most toolkits & applications have implemented in their own fashions.

You can read much more about this mechanism in the specs under [Peer-to-Peer Communication by Means of Selections](http://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.7/doc/xorg-docs/icccm/icccm.html#Peer_to_Peer_Communication_by_Means_of_Selections) in the [*Inter-Client Communication Conventions Manual*](http://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.7/doc/xorg-docs/icccm/icccm.html)

Comment: by X toolkit you mean for example Gtk?

Comment: I know that Gtk is a toolkit. But I'm wondering if code responsible for copy to clipboard from text selection and pasting using middle button is in Gtk or Qt sources... This is different copying than Ctrl-c Ctrl-v, different clipboard! And it is uniform across all toolkits. I think it has to be somewhere else. But I will check it . Thanks